# Using session values on Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I am developing a Windows Phone 7 silverlight application but, i can't use the session values to "navigate" between different pages on windows phone 7. 
I also used "Isolated Storage" but i couldn't get the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sample shows some persistence mechanisms:

http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2011/05/a-simple-windows-phone-7-mvvm-tombstoning-example/

You can also use Query Strings to pass information between two pages.  The values that make up a query string are appended to the URI.

Personally, I have a centralised controller class that gets instantiated with the main `App` class.  Any values that need passing are placed in here, in one way or another.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Adam Houldsworth for your response, it really helped me. However i found a simpler solution.

We can create a Global Variables Class in "App.xaml.cs" file and put the variables in it. The class is accessible from everywhere.

Example:

```
public static class GlobalVariables
{
   public static string my_string = "";
   public static int my_int = "";
}
```

Then we access the Global Variables class like this: 
    project_Name.GlobalVariables.variable_name;